# Is WSASend with IOCP ordered?

Tags: c, iocp

I would like to create a IOCP application to received TCP data, Once received, I will have to processing the data and write out the bytes partially. Understand that WSASend with IOCP can do the job. But I am worrying whether WSASend to the queue and does GetQueuedCompletionStatus synchronizely?. For Example:-

```
void processing_from_other_thread(...) {
...
DWORD state = still_doing1;
WSASend( ..,..,.., &state, .. );

DWORD state = still_doing2;
WSASend( ..,..,.., &state, .. );

DWORD state = still_doing3;
WSASend( ..,..,.., &state, .. );

DWORD state = Done;
PostCompletionQueue(....);
}
```

From the context above, will GetQueuedCompletionStatus getting them orderly?

```
GetQueuedCompletionStatus();
return still_doing1
GetQueuedCompletionStatus();
return still_doing2
GetQueuedCompletionStatus();
return still_doing3
GetQueuedCompletionStatus();
return Done
Continue
```

I just want to make sure the future design is correctly, I am afraid they are not orderly, For example, Return still_doing2 completed before still_doing1. The data sent might affected to client side.

Comment: 'The data sent might affected to client side' well, a TCP socket stream will ensure that the data per-socket will be transferred to the peer in the order it was sent, but IOCP does not guarantee that completion notifications will be handled in order, (or even by the same handler thread).

Comment: In the case of data sent, then the completion notification order usually does not matter.  The send buffer/s get freed, deleted or repooled and, if no error, then that's it really, so any order or handler thread will do:)   Receive completions, however, will often require more careful handling.

Comment: @Martin James Let me try to understand your mean. If in Single thread only env, I do WSASend1, WSASend2, WSASend3, When Get the queue, it might get 3, 1, 2? 1, 3, 2? But The data sent will be definitely 1,2,3?

Comment: With a TCP socket, sure, else the streaming protocol would be hopelessly broken.

Answer (score 2):

Under IOCP I/O model, the application is responsible for organizing incoming and outgoing data. In other words, **the process posts different I/O related messages to IOCP, but there is no guaranteed IOCP sends and/or receives data in that exact order**.

*This is a key part of asynchronous I/O.*

Comment: Put it this way, I only handle one overlapped object for one thread only. Will it be ordered?

Comment: Still the answer will be a no.