# I/O Completion Ports Dequeue order

Tags: winapi, win32-process, io-completion-ports

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/i-o-completion-ports:

> Please note that while the packets are queued in FIFO order they may be dequeued in a different order.

- Is this not guaranteed even in the case of a single queuing thread and a single dequing thread ?
- Is there any further information under what condition packets can be dequeued in a different order ?

Comment: packets from `KQUEUE` (iocp) is always dequeued in FIFO order. but are you know order in which it will be inserted to `KQUEUE` ? are only single thread insert packets to `KQUEUE` too ? what is different for you ? and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52023554/6401656) not the same by sense question ?

Comment: say next - in which order packets will be inserted - in same order it will be removed. so `FIFO`. simply if several threads insert packets in iocp in concurrent - you simply can not know order.but if you exactly know that packet `A` inserted before packet `B` (by some logic barrier between this) - you can be sure that packet `A` will be removed from iocp before packet `B`. but it will be removed by 2 different threads - again you can not be sure which thread first exit from `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`

Comment: do you have any doc for that ? the quote above seems to simply say the order is not guaranteed

Comment: but with every thread which call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` - if `A` inserted to queue before `B` and this thread remove both `A` and `B` - `A` garantee will be removed before `B`

Comment: the documentation frequently wrong. i have no any doc. i based on my internal knowledge how all this worked. iocp - this is `KQUEUE`. how it implemented (in win2003) [known](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c) - of course can be some changes in implementation, but fact that we have double-linked list `EntryListHead` (`KQUEUE` declared in *ntifs.h*) which processed as `FIFO`. another question - why you worry about order ? can you describe your problem ?

Comment: [*The wait discipline for Queue object is FIFO.*](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c#L119) this is visible from code (in insert and remove) and this is really native implementation - invisible how/why packet which inserted later can be removed early. another that when multiple threads insert packets and multiple remove - you already can not be sure in order, unlike you know that say some packet inserted the latest  (after all). it and will be removed latest